# Python Class inheritance Constructor fail: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a small Python OOP program in which 2 class, Flan and Outil inherit from a superclass Part. 
My problem is when I call `Flan` everything works perfectly, however when I call `Outil` the program fails silently.
The `Outil` instance is created, but it lacks all the attributes it doesn't share with `Part`.
The `Outil` instance isn't added to `Outil.list_instance_outils`, nor to `Part.list_instances`.

```
class Outil(Part):

    list_instance_outils = []    

    def __init___(self, name, part_type, nodes, elems):
        Part.__init__(self, name, part_type, nodes, elems)
        self.vect_norm = vectnorm(self.nodes[self.elems[0,1:]-1, 1:])
        self.elset = Elset(self)
        self.nset = Nset(self, refpoint=True, generate=False)
        self.SPOS = Ab_surface(self, self.elset)
        self.SNEG = Ab_surface(self, self.elset, type_surf='SNEG')
        Outil.list_instance_outils.append(self)
        Part.list_instances.append(self)

class Flan(Part):

    list_instances_flans = []    

    def __init__(self, name, part_type, nodes, elems):
        Part.__init__(self, name, part_type, nodes, elems)       
        self.vect_norm = vectnorm(self.nodes[self.elems[0,1:4]-1, 1:])
        self.elset = Elset(self)
        self.nset = Nset(self)
        self.SPOS = Ab_surface(self, self.elset)
        self.SNEG = Ab_surface(self, self.elset, type_surf='SNEG')
        Flan.list_instances_flans.append(self)        
        Part.list_instances.append(self)
```

Both this Classes inherit from Part :

```
class Part():

    list_instances = []

    def __init__(self, name, part_type, nodes, elems):
        self.name = name
        self.name_instance = self.name + '-1'
        self.part_type = part_type
        self.elems = elems
        self.nodes = nodes
        offset = np.min(self.elems[:, 1:])-1
        self.nodes[:, 0] -= offset
        self.elems[:, 1:] -= offset
```

I cannot stress enough that I have no error message whatsoever.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please can you indent your code properly?

Comment: OMFG ! I found my problem...
in Class Outil I wrote __init___ instead of __init__
(when you see it... 3 hours..)

Comment: When you say "but it lacks all the attributes it doesn't share with Part", how do you know that? Show some test code that fails.

Comment: Good work -- the rubber duck strikes again! (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wrote `__init__` with ***three*** trailing underscores instead of two in `Outil`.

Because of this, it doesn't get called -- `Part.__init__` gets called instead. That's why the class is created but it lacks the attributes beyond what are in `Part`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this sort of problem, the best thing to do is to run the code through the debugger.

Get your classes into the python interpreter (import, paste, whatever you like), then [call pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#module-pdb): `import pdb; pdb.run('Outil()')`. You can now step through the code to see what is happening.